# NextJS/ReactJS + Vercel CORS issue only in production - blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, cors

I'm getting a CORS error when calling an API endpoint from a function, but when I call it from getServerSideProps() then it works. This only happens in production on Vercel, on localhost everything works.

CORS error:

```
Access to fetch at 'https://myurl.com/api/products' from origin 'https://www.myurl.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

The following works

```
export async function getServerSideProps() {
  const resp = await fetch(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL}/products`);
  const products = await resp.json();
  return { props: { products } };
}
```

Function which calls API endpoint (this causes an error)

```
  const refreshList = async () => {
    const resp = await fetch(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL}/products`); // error already occurs here
    const products = await resp.json();
  };
```

Simple API endpoint to retrieve products

```
export default async function handler(req, res) {
  if (req.method == "GET") {
    const products = await prisma.product.findMany();
    return res.send(products);
  }
```

Can anyone tell me why this happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`https://example.com` and `https://www.example.com` will be considered as 2 different domains. Hence CORS restriction will be there.

When calling the API from `getServerSideProps` the call happens from server and not in the browser. CORS is enforced by client browser for security reasons.

Make sure `https://www` is redirected to `https://example.com` or vice versa and update the path `process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL` in `.env` accordingly. (Make sure you restart server after changes in `.env` file)

Another method is to dynamical find the base URL and use that in fetch.

eg: Using `window.location.origin`

```
const resp = await fetch(`${window.location.origin}/products`);
```

Comment: Learned something new, and you saved me a lot of headache, thanks a lot!